# How can i extend Lucene with a language model?

Tags: java, lucene, similarity, dirichlet

Good evening everyone!
So, i have as project "extend lucene with a language model", i tried adding 2, 3 lines to my code like this:
on search.java

```
LMDirichletSimilarity similarity = new LMDirichletSimilarity(2000f);  
indexSearcher.setSimilarity(similarity);
```

and  on index.java

```
LMDirichletSimilarity similarity = new LMDirichletSimilarity(2000f);
config.setSimilarity(similarity);
```

but i don't think it's that easy! maybe i should write an algorithm or something ? please if you have some answers help me
thank you ^_^

Comment: The code in the question replaces Lucene's default [BM25Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html) scorer (see more info [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html)) with a different scorer - the [LMDirichletSimilarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/LMDirichletSimilarity.html) scorer. If that's what you want, you are all set.

Comment: The LMDirichletSimilarity source code is [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/LMDirichletSimilarity.java), if you are interested. (Don't ask me to explain how it works.)

Comment: @andrewjames i want too ad an unigram language model to lucene unsing diricglet smoothing but i didn't found and algorthm doing that :/

Comment: I may be completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do (if so, my apologies), but... dirichlet smoothing is already implemented (you already found it) and "unigram" in the context of Lucene means (to me) single word tokens - for example, as generated by the Standard Analyzer (in contrast to other Lucene n-gram analyzers or shingle analyzers). Sometimes, it's more helpful to look at the [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/language-models-in-elasticsearch) documentation than the Lucene documentation, for more insight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a language model similarity method in `LMJelinekMercerSimilarity` and the implementation is:

```
protected float score(BasicStats stats, float freq, float docLen) {
    return stats.getBoost()
            * (float) Math.log(1 + ((1 - alpha) * freq / docLen)
                            / (alpha * ((LMStats) stats).getCollectionProbability()));
}
```

This method is implementation of this formula: `(1-lambda) * P(w|d) + lambda * P(w|Collection)` If you look at the method above and the language model formula you see there is a bit difference between them. It is because Lucene's factorizes the expression `lambda * P(w|Collection)` from the language model formula and create a new formula: `lambda * P(w|Collection) * ( ( (1-lambda) * P(w|d) / lambda * P(w|Collection) ) +1 )`
then it removes the `lambda * P(w|Collection)` because of ranking (It doesn't affect ranking) and just calculate `( ( (1-lambda) * P(w|d) / lambda * P(w|Collection) ) +1 )`. you can see it is similar the method above. but there is a little difference and that is Logarithm. In IR community they use Logarithm because that is easy to deal and easily evaluated by computers. so the final statement is:
`log ( ( ( (1-lambda) * P(w|d) / lambda * P(w|Collection) ) +1 ) )`
The method above is a `protected` so you can derive that method and implement your own.

Comment: What is wrong with using the `LMDirichletSimilarity` smoothing scorer already provided by Lucene [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/LMDirichletSimilarity.html#score-org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BasicStats-double-double-), since that is the one the OP mentioned?